# Column Grouping in SSRS Report

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, grouping, ssrs-grouping

```
WITH Members as (
select Members, ReportingMonth from Members ) ,

Calls as (
select Received, Answered, Abandoned,ReportingMonth from Calls ) ,

Rate as (
select Rate from Rate ) ,

Complaints as (
select ComplaintsReceived, ComplaintsProcessed,ReportingMonth from Complaints ) 


select M.Members,
M.ReportMonth,
R.Rate,
C.Received,
C.Answered, 
C.Abandoned, 
CO.ComplaintsReceived, 
CO.ComplaintsProcessed

from Members as M
left join  Calls C ON M.ReportMonth = C.ReportMonth
left join Rate R ON M.ReportMonth = R.ReportMonth
LEFT JOIN Complaints CO ON M.ReportMonth = CO.ReportMonth
```

Hello friends, i have above query as a dataset to my monthly SSRS report. I have to group the report by ReportingMonth. I tried to group it by column grouping but it's not giving me the result i want. I want to group all the data in the select list by reporting month which is used in column group in my SSRS report. I see in select list it's coming from Members cte so the column group only populates the members data.

Is there any way to group all the fields in the select list by reporting month?

Comment: What's not correct? Other than your **ReportMonth** in the query, it looks like it should work by grouping the column by **ReportingMonth**. You might want to add ISNULL( ,0) around the number fields (Rate, Rec'd, Ans...) in the last SELECT so you don't have to deal with blanks in the report.

Comment: Thanks. I used ReportMonth as a column group in SSRS, it did  group for Members filed as it is in the select list from members cte but did not group all other fields in the final select list.

Comment: It sounds like you added the **Column Grouping** for the ReportingMonth and are SUMming the Member count. To SUM the other columns, you would need to add a column **INSIDE the current group** to have it **SUM** in the **Reporting Month group** (right-click on your Members cell and **Insert Column -> Inside Group - Right**.

Comment: Thanks man. Yes, grouping was wrong in the SSRS Designer. Used your logic, it worked. Thanks again.